# see whole chart base on my data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have chart that reads data from a serial port and my data are unlimited. I want to extended range of my chart that showing data to me.

I don't know how to do that. This is my code that adding data to chart:

```
public void AddData()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    InputData = ComPort.ReadByte();
    object firstByte = InputData;

    if (ComPort.IsOpen == true)
    {
        s = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(firstByte));
        temp1 += s;
        lock (firstByte)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(firstByte) == 13)
            {
                temp = temp1;
                temp1 = "";
                ComPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                _valuelist.Add(Convert.ToInt32(temp));
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append);
                var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0} {1}", temp, DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ff")) + "\r\n");
                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                fs.Close();
                chart1.ResetAutoValues();
                if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
                {
                    while (chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue < now.AddSeconds(-5).ToOADate())
                    {
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = now.AddSeconds(5).ToOADate();
                    }
                }
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(now.ToOADate(), _valuelist[_valuelist.Count - 1]);
                chart1.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are already setting the AxisX.Minimum/Maximum. Expect for keeping them at Auto (ie.e double.NaN) that should work, unless your values are wrong.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: _how can i do that ?_ - What?

Comment: make AxisX.Minimum/Maximum be auto

Comment: They are by default. So one way is to not change them. Or you can set them: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN` etc..

Comment: when i do that chart removing previous point and my data be come Discontinuous

Comment: That sounds weird. It often helps to show a screenshot of a chart..

Comment: ohhh thanks i have made  a mistake that put code in the loop thank you for your response.